# Consumir un servicio https en asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, asp

Quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy tratando de consumir un servicio a mi aplicación asp.net c#  a que el servicio que quiero consumir es de **.ashx**

pero cuando agrego la referencia de servicio me sale un error como la imagen que adjunto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que me puedan ayudar o porque motivo no me deja consumir el servicio que quiero consumir es este:

https://robinacademia.com/p.ashx?o=63&e=2&f=pb&r=REQUEST_SESSION_ID&t=TRANSACTION_ID

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            string URLString = "https://robinacademia.com/p.ashx?o=63&e=2&f=pb&r=REQUEST_SESSION_ID&t=TRANSACTION_ID";

            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);
            string resultado = "";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // El nodo es un elemento.
                        resultado += "<" + reader.Name;

                        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Lee los atributos.
                            Console.Write(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
                        resultado += ">";
                        resultado += "\n";
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Muestra el texto en cada elemento.
                        resultado += reader.Value;
                        if (resultado == "<result>\n<code>\n1")
                        {
                            txtnumero1.Text = reader.Value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            txtnumero2.Text = reader.Value;
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Muestra el final del elemento.
                        resultado += "</" + reader.Name;
                        resultado += ">";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte nos tienes que enseñar el código con el que estas realizando la petición para saber que estas haciendo mal

Comment: @AnonimoPer es un servicio externo es decir sobre el servicio que coloque no tengo el codigo. sOLO QUIERO CONSUMIR ESE SERVICIO ya que si colocas ese link que coloque en el chrome si funciona.

Comment: Me refería a que indiques el código de como consumes el servicio

Comment: @AnonimoPer creo que en visual studio en c# solo hay una manera de agregar un servicio

Comment: Pensaba que lo estabas consumiendo mediante código lo siento. Puedes usar este ejemplo: WebClient client = new WebClient ();
var textoDevuelto = client.DownloadString ("https://robinacademia.com/p.ashx?o=63&e=2&f=pb&r=REQUEST_SESSION_ID&t=TRANSACTION_ID");

Comment: @AnonimoPer puedes mandar un pantallaso como respuesta como lo estas colocando POR FAVOR hermano

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76657/discussion-between-pierro-and-anonimoper).

Comment: @AnonimoPer estoy colocando asi en codebing.
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          WebClient client = new WebClient ();
          var textoDevuelto = client.DownloadString ("https://robinacademia.com/p.ashx?o=63&e=2&f=pb&r=REQUEST_SESSION_ID&t=TRANSACTION_ID%22");
           

        }

Comment: @AnonimoPer en mi pagina cuando ejecute me vota  en blanco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te adjunto el código que he probado y funciona:

```
    string URLString = "https://robinacademia.com/p.ashx?o=63&e=2&f=pb&r=REQUEST_SESSION_ID&t=TRANSACTION_ID";
    //String URLString = "http://localhost/books.xml";
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);
    string resultado = "";
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element: // El nodo es un elemento.
                resultado += "<" + reader.Name;

                while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Lee los atributos.
                    Console.Write(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
                resultado+= ">";
                resultado += "\n";
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text: //Muestra el texto en cada elemento.
                resultado += reader.Value;
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Muestra el final del elemento.
                resultado += "</" + reader.Name;
                resultado += ">";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: lo puse como la imagen que he actualizado en mi pregunta pero al momento de ejecutar sale en blanco

Comment: en la imagen que pusiste se te ha colado % miralo bien, copia la url que me pusiste bien por eso seguramente te salga en blanco

Comment: ahora le puse igual pero cuando ejecuto sale en blanco la pagina

Comment: @anonimosper porque cuando tu ejecutas te vota unos resultados verdad como podria coger esos resultados

Comment: He modificado el código y dejo almacenado el resultado en la variable, espero que te sirva.

Comment: @anonimos como hago para mostrar solo las respuestas en un label?

Comment: es decir quiero colocar 2 label
y un label que se coloque el resultado de solo uno
y el otro label el otro resultado

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta pero para asignar a un Mabel supongo que tendrá una propiedad text o una función SetText() si la respuesta te sirvió marcarlo como respuesta por si le sirve a otra persona

Comment: edite mi pregunta ahi puse los label o texbox pero no se si estara bien

Comment: estas mi hermano

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178625/como-consumir-servicio-ashx-sin-redireccionar-asp-net-c