# como podria ejecutar el servicio ashx con asp.Net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas estoy trabajando en asp.net c# web , ejecutar este servicio aspx

por lo cual utilize este codigo xml , sin redireccionar

```
DateTime DiaActual;
            DiaActual = DateTime.Now;
            String VariableEnviar;
            String Obteneyear; String Mes; String Dia; String Hora; String Minuto; String Segundos;
            Obteneyear = DiaActual.Year.ToString();
            Mes = DiaActual.Month.ToString();
            Dia = DiaActual.Day.ToString();
            Hora = DiaActual.Hour.ToString();
            Minuto = DiaActual.Minute.ToString();
            Segundos = DiaActual.Second.ToString();


            VariableEnviar = "000000" + "-ASK" + "-" + Obteneyear + "-" + Mes + "-" + Dia + " " + Hora + ":" + Minuto + ":" + Segundos;

            string URLString = "https://robinacademia.com/p.ashx?o=63&e=2&f=pb&r=r_parameter&t=" + VariableEnviar;


            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);
            string resultado = "";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // El nodo es un elemento.
                        resultado += "<" + reader.Name;

                        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Lee los atributos.
                            Console.Write(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
                        resultado += ">";
                        resultado += "\n";
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Muestra el texto en cada elemento.
                        resultado += reader.Value;
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Muestra el final del elemento.
                        resultado += "</" + reader.Name;
                        resultado += ">";
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Pero lo malo que no me muestra correctamente el mesage .

ya que si ese enlace lo coloco en mi navegador :

**https://robinacademia.com/p.ashx?o=63&e=2&f=pb&r=r_parameter&t=000000-ASK-2018-7-7 11:12:5**

sale otro diferente lo que deseo es que se verifique igual como se muestra en navegador cuando coloco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente tambien con este codigo pero sale igual:

```
 String Label;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Label = client.DownloadString("https://robinacademia.com/p.ashx?o=63&e=2&f=pb&r=r_parameter&t=000000-ASK-2018-7-7 11:12:5");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error no parece ser la llamada, si no como construis la respuesta que vos estas buscando.... :/

Comment: siempre va a ser diferente porque en uno, los headers lo pone el navegador... Si utilizas POSTMAN tienes el mismo XML...

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver el redireccionar en todo esto?

Comment: en ese caso, edita tu pregunta porque el título está fuera de contexto con la descripción. La solución presentada (ya eliminada) estaba de acuerdo a lo que has intentado en tu pregunta, sin embargo, tampoco es lo que estás buscando. Coloca el comportamiento esperado también. Buena suerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ReadXMLfromASHXhandler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String Label;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Label = client.DownloadString("https://robinacademia.com/p.ashx?o=63&e=2&f=pb&r=r_parameter&t=000000-ASK-2018-7-7 11:12:5");

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Label);

            XElement code = doc.Descendants("code").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement msg = doc.Descendants("msg").FirstOrDefault();

            string codeValue = code.Value;
            string msgValue = msg.Value;           
            Console.WriteLine(codeValue);
            Console.WriteLine(msgValue);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Lectura recomendada:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/es-Es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xdocument-class-overview
- https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: hermano porque aun me sigue apareciendo con resultado receveid y cuando ese mismo link pongo en la pagina me manda otro resultado.
me dijieron que consuma ese servicio en ashx para mandarle el ultimo parametro que esta t=

Comment: deseo consumir ese web service que va estar en mi aplicativo y mandarle el parametro pero ellos dicen que no les llega o no reciben.

Comment: Por los headers... Utiliza POSTMAN para que verifiques...

Comment: pero no es mvc , ni mvc core

Comment: ¿Has intentado?

Comment: si , pero veo que no me sale me estaba guiando de aqui : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226086/postman-request-to-c-sharp-web-api-gives-a-null-property

Comment: Hasta donte te he entendido, quieres obtener el valor de cada variable: código y mensaje. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: solo me dijieron que envíe ese ashx y mandando él parametro que es él último t= pero lo que me dicen que no le llega él psrametro